# In SQL Server, Which select statement(s)/table(s) is returned in a table-valued function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table-valued function **without** a return variable (no variables are specified to be returned). The table contains three giant CTEs followed by a select statement that uses the three CTEs as well as some other tables.

I am just wondering what exactly is returned here by this function? I know that the obvious answer is to just say SELECT * FROM DBO.[TEST_FUNCTION]. But I am just wondering **how** SQL Server is deciding on the result-set to return? What exactly happens when a function is defined in the fashion below? What if CTEs had the same column names? Which CTE is returned? or is it the last select statement that's returned? what if there were multiple select statements after the CTEs? What exactly decides what is returned by the function?? Thank you very much

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TEST_FUNCTION](@PARAMATER INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
WITH 
CTE 1 AS 
(SELECT STATEMENTS),
CTE 2 AS 
(SELECT STATEMENTS),
CTE 3 AS
(SELECT STATEMENTS)


--Separate from the above three CTEs code continues with another select statement
SELECT Columns, 
UNION CTE 2
INNER JOIN CTE 3, etc.
```

Comment: CTEs are NOT returned from a table valued function. The ONLY thing returned is the output from a select statement. Your code here has only 1 select statement. The ctes are "filled" with a select statement but they function as an inline view. And what if your ctes had the same column name? Have you tried to see what happens if you have duplicate column names in a table valued function?

Comment: @SeanLange that's true, my code only has one select statement, but I was wondering of cases where you may end up with multiple select statements. And I will try same column names now.

Comment: Did you notice the keyword RETURN? That is what is returned from your function. Any code after that would not execute (and probably won't compile but I have never tried). If you have a select statement prior to the return you have turned your inline table valued function to a multi-statement table valued function which is poor for performance.

Comment: @SeanLange I am not sure what you mean, Return is all the way on top and so many statements occur afterwards.

Comment: Actually there is only 1 statement after RETURN. It just so happens to begin with several CTEs. Remember that a CTE is basically just an inline view. Your code here creates a few of these CTEs and then has a select statement to pull data from them. That is what is being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an inline table valued function which means there is no return statement. You can tell it's inline because of this syntax: RETURNS TABLE AS. 
Inline Table valued functions are almost identical to views except that they:
1. Can accept parameters
2. Can't be indexed

The CTEs in your example are identical to subqueries except for a few differences which are outside of the scope of your question.

Note that these two queries return the same result and are identical in how they are processed:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT v FROM (VALUES (1),(2)) t(v)),
cte2 AS (SELECT v FROM cte1),
cte3 AS (SELECT v FROM cte2)
SELECT * 
FROM cte3;

SELECT v
FROM
(
  SELECT v
  FROM
  (
    SELECT v
    FROM (SELECT v FROM (VALUES (1),(2)) t(v)) AS cte1
  ) AS cte2
) AS cte3;
```

The CTE format has cleaner syntax when nesting but, like the subquery example, it is just a single query. Hopefully that makes sense.

Note that this query:

```
WITH 
CTE1 AS (SELECT 1   AS x),
CTE2 AS (SELECT 20  AS x),
CTE3 AS (SELECT 100 AS x);

--Separate from the above three CTEs code continues with another select statement
SELECT x AS x1, x*2 AS x2 
FROM CTE1
UNION ALL
SELECT CTE2.x, CTE3.x
FROM CTE2
INNER JOIN CTE3 ON CTE2.x <> CTE3.x;
```

Returns this single result set:

```
x1          x2
----------- -----------
1           2
20          100
```

If you wrap it in an inline table valued function it will return the same thing:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TEST_FUNCTION](@PARAMATER INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
WITH 
CTE1 AS (SELECT 1   AS x),
CTE2 AS (SELECT 20  AS x),
CTE3 AS (SELECT 100 AS x)


--Separate from the above three CTEs code continues with another select statement
SELECT x AS x1, x*2 AS x2 
FROM CTE1
UNION ALL
SELECT CTE2.x, CTE3.x
FROM CTE2
INNER JOIN CTE3 ON CTE2.x <> CTE3.x;
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.TEST_FUNCTION(NULL);
```

Here the function returns the same as above. Note that I'm not doing anything with the sample parameter.

Comment: THank you so much for your answer. This will sound dumb, but in all of your examples you had only one select statement in the end (or UNIONed multiple select statements). What if you had two completely separate select statements? SELECT product, price from CTE1, and then another select statement SELECT dateOfPurchase, dateOfExpirey FROM CTE2. I am using two sets of irrelevant tables, just to bring an unusual case where you have multiple selects at the end without connection.

Answer (score 1):

TVP without a return variable is inline table-valued function. These functions very similar to views and expands at parse time. See query plan - there no function calls. SQL server process it as subquery.

> Inline functions can be used to achieve the functionality of
>   parameterized views.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396